# Batch: Copy File from different Subfolders with certain file name to other destination

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy-paste

I am total beginner and need help with copying of files in windows. I have xlsx files in in different subfolders. The name of the files that I want to copy contain (but are not limited) to `"Reporting Assessment Tool"`. I would like to copy all files containing that name and bring them to flat source destination (don't need the folder structure).

source: c:\users\name\desktop\upload
destination: c:\users\source\desktop\tool

So far I have tried the following

```
cd /D "c:\users\jubalkheimer\desktop\upload" @for /r %%a in ("*Reporting Assessment Tool.xlsx") do ( 
copy "%%a" "c:\users\jubalkheimer\desktop\tool\"%%~a")
```

I am not receiving a error message, but files don't get copied....

Can you help?
Many thanks

Comment: Thanks - code added. in the original comment

Comment: Put quotation marks around `*Reporting Assessment Tool.xlsx` and replace `"%%a"` by `"%%~a"`; otherwise the white-spaces disturb...

Comment: ...and just a side note: do not start the script by double-clicking; instead, open a command prompt window, manoeuvre to the parent path and run the script by typing its name; so you can see its output and error messages...

Comment: I have updated the code above. Is ok? I tried to run it by double clicking- it would not work. I don't know what ro type in the command prompt window as suggested...

Comment: I just noticed an `echo ` in front of the `copy` command which just displays the `copy` command line; remove the `echo `, then it should work...

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the code. Hower it is still not working. and tried to open the batchfile from the prompt as mentioned by you but I am receiving a error message that the bat file is not  recognized as a internal or external command.

Comment: The source `c:\users\jubalkheimer\desktop\upload` should be enclosed in `""` too and preceded by the command `cd /D `...

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the code again. Now I receive the error message the path (until the start of the do) doe not exist. I am quite sure that I have typed the correct path. But also the line all the way to do is not a path right?

Comment: In front of @`for` insert a `&` which comstitutes a command separator (so to put two commands, `cd` and `for` im your case) into one line...

Answer (score 0):

The batch file code for this task could be:

```
@echo off
for /R "%USERPROFILE%\desktop\upload" %%I in ("*Reporting Assessment Tool.xlsx") do (
    copy /-Y "%%I" "%USERPROFILE%\desktop\tool\%%~nxI"
)
```

This could be done also with a single command line in batch file:

```
@for /R "%USERPROFILE%\desktop\upload" %%I in ("*Reporting Assessment Tool.xlsx") do @copy /-Y "%%I" "%USERPROFILE%\desktop\tool\%%~nxI"
```

The case-sensitive loop variable `I` holds on each loop run the name of a file with full path without surrounding double quotes found in the specified directory or any subdirectory of that directory matching the file name pattern `*Reporting Assessment Tool.xlsx`.

For copying the found file with prompting the user of the batch file for overwriting an already existing file with same name in target directory it is necessary to specify as first parameter the string assigned to the loop variable and as second parameter the target path and just file name and file extension of the found file without path. This explains the usage of `"%%I"` (file name with extension and full path enclosed in double quotes) and `"Target Path\%%~nxI"` (just file name and file extension with fixed destination path enclosed in double quotes) on **COPY** command line.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `copy /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`

`%USERPROFILE%` references the predefined environment variable `USERPROFILE` which holds the path to profile directory of the current user account.

It would be very easily possible to do this task also without the usage of a batch file using Windows Explorer.

1. Navigate to folder `%USERPROFILE%\desktop\upload`
2. Run in that folder a search for `*Reporting Assessment Tool.xlsx`
   Windows Explorer automatically searches recursive in that folder and all subfolders for files matching this file name pattern.
3. Select all found files with <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> (select All).
4. Prepare for copying all selected files with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> (Copy).
5. Navigate to folder `%USERPROFILE%\desktop\tool`
6. Paste the files prepared for copying with <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> (Paste) which results in copying the files now.

Comment: Merci! It worked. Great thanks also for your explanations!